# Testing MediaBrowserServiceCompat Implementation

Tags: android, testing, bluetooth

i am developing an audio player. The player is controllable over bluetooth (pause, play, ...). The next thing i want to implement is to select tracks from a playlist by the means of an MediaBrowserServiceCompat service. The only testing client so far is my car and this is very unhandy.

Does anybody knows a bluetooth (or other) client i can use to test an implementation of a MediaBrowserServiceCompat service ?

Regards, Rainer

Answer (score 1):

You can run the android-media-controller sample (see https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller) on the same device and test various aspects of MediaBrowserServiceCompat.

Hth,
Peter